# Heroku app crashing, Redux seems to not install properly?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-redux

I have defined my `store.js` as,

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers"; //we dont have to put index.js because its called index.js

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
); //spread operator '...'

export default store;
```

I have got it working with Chrome, it seems fine. When I deploy to heroku, I run this script,

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Now, my app works fine.. however only with chrome, which leads me to believe there may be something wrong with my script. Not sure where to go from here, I seem to have followed the docs. Is it maybe a compatibility issue?

Comment: I dont think you need the `initialState`

Comment: @MikeK It's an optional argument to `createStore`...

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers"; //we dont have to put index.js because its called index.js

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ &&
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()) ||
          compose
      : compose
  )
); //spread operator '...'

export default store;
```